# Gradle - Include external projects as dependencies into .jar

Tags: eclipse, gradle, jar, executable-jar, multi-project

I've two projects as **dependencies**: A, B. ( **NOT SUB-projects** but **EXTERNAL projects** )

My third project C, depends on both A and B.

I've already defined the settings.gradle in this way:

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'project_C'
include ':common_library'
project(":project_A").projectDir = file("../project_A")
include ':project_A'
project(":project_B").projectDir = file("../project_B")
```

**build.gradle**

```
// ************** Include dependencies as local .jars
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'lib')


    // ************** Compile the project on which this depends on
    implementation project(':project_A')
    implementation project(':project_B')


    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


// *********** MODIFY the standard JAR task, including Main file (for executable jars) and pack all it's dependencies
jar {
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            configurations.runtime.filter( {! (it.name =~ /.*\.pom/ )}).collect {
                it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
            }
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "Main"
    }
}
```

At this point, it **builds with success**.

But when i try to execute it as jar, it gives me errors about **"not included dependencies"** related to the **project_A** and **project_B** classes.

Someone that has already faced off this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful which explains creating a fat jar which includes dependent jar.
https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar